# Getting selected option data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fetch data from currently selected option. I came out with this.
Could i somehow improve it or is this fine?

Im specially not sure about the current option selector.

```
<option data-id='one'></option>

....

$('select#first').change(function(){

var smth = $("option:selected",this).data('id');
alert(smth);


});
```

Comment: Does it work? Have you tested it?

Comment: It should work. Are you creating the `select` dynamically? And are you sure its id is `first`?

Comment: Why attribute data if you can use standarized attribute value?

Comment: Yes, select's options are created dynamically.

Comment: @alberto its new html5 standard. And i need more than just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like just this should work,,

```
    $('select#first').change(function() {
    var smth = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-id');
    alert(smth);
});​

   OR

$('select#first').change(function() {
    var smth = $(this).find('option:selected').data('id');
    alert(smth);
});​
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rfNCg/)

Comment: That doesnt work, it says undefined. Option has data values, not select.

Comment: Works fine now. Do you think .find() is faster/better than :selected?

Comment: Not sure exactly.. But it will filter out the elements.. need to check at http://jsperf.com/